# How could I use a string value in the middle of a file name in C++?

Tags: c++

For instance, I want a file to be created using the myfile.open that has the title    "m[name]f", with [name] being a string inputted by the user. I know how to collect strings, but how do I make it a part IN THE MIDDLE of the file name?

In BASIC, I would use:

```
    open "m";namestring$;"f.txt"
```

How would I do this in C++?

Edit: Unfamiliar with the term "string concatenation" at the time.

Comment: use std::basic_string or raw strings functions.

Comment: Search for "string concatenation" - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BC%2B%2B%5D+concatenate+string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::string filename = "m";
filename += namestring;
filename += "f.txt";
std::ifstream my_file(filename.c_str());
```

The `std::string` is the C++ string type.  The `+=` operator is concatenation.  I'm assuming that `namestring` is another `std::string` variable.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I wish these downvoters would leave comments.

Answer (score -2):

Below code will work .

```
    #include <fstream>      // std::ofstream
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main () {

  std::string str;
 std::cin>>str;//take input from user (can also use getline if input contain white space)
  std::ofstream ofs;//you may use other I/O
  ofs.open ((std::string(str+".txt")).c_str(), std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);

  ofs << " more lorem ipsum";

  ofs.close();

  return 0;
}
```